# Media Query works when resizing browser to mobile dimensions, but styling breaks when device is selected in developer tools

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, responsive

So this is an interesting one that I've come across. I have a media query for mobile responsiveness with `@media screen and (max-width:700px){`. When I resize my browser (Chrome) from greater than 700px to something smaller, the media query functions perfection. In inspect mode, when I switch devices after resizing my browser from 700px to something below it, the media query appears to function properly. However, when I refresh the page and immediately select a mobile browser, the CSS styling breaks. Totally lost on why this is happening. I have already inserted   `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css" />` to have it work with with Chrome. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Fugaz+One|Lato|Montserrat:900|News+Cycle|Yellowtail" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 

</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper"> <!-- wrapper -->


        <header>
        <nav id='cssmenu'>
        <div class="logo"><a href="home.html">Responsive </a></div>
        <div id="head-mobile"></div>
        <div class="button"></div>
        <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='#'>HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>ABOUT</a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href='#'>Topic 1</a></li>
             <li><a href='#'>Topic 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Topic 3</a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub1</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub2</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub3</a></li>

           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Topic 4</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Topic 5</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>s1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>s2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>s3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>topic 5</a></li>

        </ul>
        </nav>
        </header>

<div class="parallax">
  <div class="opener">
    <div class="opener-align">
    Title 1
   </div>
  </div>
  <div data-scroll-reveal class="opener-second">
    <div class="opener-second-align">
    Title 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax2">
  <div class="parallax-transition-1">
    <div class="services-annoucement-header">
      Three specialized services:
    </div>
    <div class="topic-wrapper"><div class="parallax-icons"><img class="hp-image-size" src="img1.png"/><div class="icon-text">CSS <br />Optimization</div></div>
    <div class="topic-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc felis turpis, pharetra quis risus at, convallis fringilla ipsum. Etiam elit dui, pellentesque porttitor bibendum sed, molestie sit amet dolor. 
   </div>
   </div>
    <div class="topic-wrapper">
      <div class="parallax-icons"><img class="hp-image-size" src="services.png"/><div class="icon-text">CSS <br />Advertising</div></div>
    <div class="topic-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc felis turpis, pharetra quis risus at, convallis fringilla ipsum. Etiam elit dui, pellentesque porttitor bibendum sed, molestie sit amet dolor. 
   </div>
  </div>

    <div class="topic-wrapper"><div class="parallax-icons"><img class="services" src="whatever.png" /><div class="icon-text">Whatever <br />Thing</div></div>
    <div class="topic-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc felis turpis, pharetra quis risus at, convallis fringilla ipsum. Etiam elit dui, pellentesque porttitor bibendum sed, molestie sit amet dolor. 
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax3">
<div class="parallax-transition-2">
  <div class="services-annoucement-header">
    Two additional points
  </div>
  <div class="topic-wrapper2"><div class="parallax-icons"><img class="hp-image-size" src="randomicon.png"/><div class="icon-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  </div></div>
  <div class="topic-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc felis turpis, pharetra quis risus at, convallis fringilla ipsum. Etiam elit dui, pellentesque porttitor bibendum sed, molestie sit amet dolor. 
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="topic-wrapper2"><div class="parallax-icons"><img class="hp-image-size" src="img.png"/><div class="icon-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div></div>
 <div class="topic-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc felis turpis, pharetra quis risus at, convallis fringilla ipsum. Etiam elit dui, pellentesque porttitor bibendum sed, molestie sit amet dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc felis turpis, pharetra quis risus at, convallis fringilla ipsum. Etiam elit dui, pellentesque porttitor bibendum sed, molestie sit amet dolor. 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="parallax4">
<div class="parallax-transition-2">



</div>
</div>
  </div> <!-- wrapper -->




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
/*CSS RESET*/


html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones. Increase/decrease the pixels if needed */
/* @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .parallax {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}

 media queries above */

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.parallax {
        /* The image used */
    background-image: url("sunlife-building-mtl-digital-marketing.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;


    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.parallax2 {
        /* The image used */
    background-image: url("st-josephs-oratory-montreal-services.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.parallax3 {
        /* The image used */
    background-image: url("montreal-skyline-seo.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.parallax4 {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("olympic-stadium-montreal-seo-architecture.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* --- nav below --- */


/* --- nav above --- */
/* --- general below --- */


.opener {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    position:relative;
    top:30%;
    color: rgba(14, 115, 230, 1.0);
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.opener-align {
    width:80%;
    background-color: rgba(245, 243, 243, 0.9);
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:5px 15px 5px 15px;
}

.opener-second {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    position:relative;
    top:45%;
    color: #DCB518;
    font-family: 'Yellowtail', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.opener-second-align {
    width:60%;
    background-color: rgba(42, 41, 33, 0.7);
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:5px 15px 5px 15px;
}


.parallax-transition-1 {
    text-align: center;
    top: 20%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

.parallax-transition-2 {
    text-align: center;
    top: 15%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; /*check this */
    width:100%;
}

.services-annoucement-header {
    background-color: rgba(245, 243, 243, 0.9);
    border-radius: 15px;
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto 40px auto;
    font-family: 'Yellowtail', cursive;
    color: rgba(14, 115, 230, 1.0);
    font-size:40px;
    padding:15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.hp-image-size {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

.topic-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 230px;
    background-color: rgba(245, 243, 243, 0.9);
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    height: 410px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size:1em;
}

.topic-wrapper:hover {
    background-color: rgba(99,99,99,0.75);
    color: white;
}

.topic-wrapper2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35%;
    min-width: 330px;
    background-color: rgba(245, 243, 243, 0.9);
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    height: 460px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.topic-wrapper2:hover {
    background-color: rgba(99,99,99,0.75);
    color: white;
}

.topic-text {
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
    text-align:justify;
    margin: 0 15px 5px 15px;
}

.parallax-icons {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
}

.icon-text {
    margin-top:5px;
}


/* --- general above --- */
@font-face {
    font-family: exo;
    src:url(Exo-regular.otf);
}

/* --- forms below --- */
textarea {
    resize:none;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 575px;
    background-color: rgba(245, 243, 243, 0.9);
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    height: 400px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

input {
    margin:auto;
}

.formservicesspacing {
    display:block;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

/* --- media queries below --- */

*{margin:0;padding:0;text-decoration:none}
body{background:#555;}
header{position:relative;width:100%;background:#333;}
.logo{position:relative;z-index:123;padding:10px;font:18px verdana;color:#6DDB07;float:left;width:15%}
.logo a{color:#6DDB07;}
nav{position:relative;width:700px;margin:0 auto;} /* fixed this for right scroll */
#cssmenu,#cssmenu ul,#cssmenu ul li,#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu #head-mobile{border:0;list-style:none;line-height:1;display:block;position:relative;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
#cssmenu:after,#cssmenu > ul:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;visibility:hidden;line-height:0;height:0}
#cssmenu #head-mobile{display:none}
#cssmenu{font-family:sans-serif;background:#333}
#cssmenu > ul > li{float:left}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{padding:17px;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;text-decoration:none;color:#ddd;font-weight:700;}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul li.active a{color:#fff}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover,#cssmenu ul li.active:hover,#cssmenu ul li.active,#cssmenu ul li.has-sub.active:hover{background:#448D00!important;-webkit-transition:background .3s ease;-ms-transition:background .3s ease;transition:background .3s ease;}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a{padding-right:30px}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:11px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{position:absolute;top:19px;right:14px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:'';-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:23px;height:0}
#cssmenu ul ul{position:absolute;left:-9999px}
#cssmenu ul ul li{height:0;-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;background:#333;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover{}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul{left:auto}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li{height:35px}
#cssmenu ul ul ul{margin-left:100%;top:0}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.15);padding:11px 15px;width:170px;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;color:#ddd;font-weight:400;}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a{border-bottom:0}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover{color:#fff}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after{position:absolute;top:16px;right:11px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before{position:absolute;top:13px;right:14px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:'';-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:17px;height:0}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover,#cssmenu ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover{background:#363636;}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a{border-left:1px solid #333}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active> a{border-top:1px solid #333}

@media screen and (max-width:700px){
.logo{position:absolute;top:0;left: 0;width:100%;height:46px;text-align:center;padding:10px 0 0 0 ;float:none}
.logo2{display:none}
nav{width:100%;}
#cssmenu{width:100%}
#cssmenu ul{width:100%;display:none}
#cssmenu ul li{width:100%;border-top:1px solid #444}
#cssmenu ul li:hover{background:#363636;}
#cssmenu ul ul li,#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li{height:auto}
#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu ul ul li a{width:100%;border-bottom:0}
#cssmenu > ul > li{float:none}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{padding-left:25px}
#cssmenu ul ul li{background:#333!important;}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover{background:#363636!important}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a{padding-left:35px}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{color:#ddd;background:none}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a{color:#fff}
#cssmenu ul ul,#cssmenu ul ul ul{position:relative;left:0;width:100%;margin:0;text-align:left}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before{display:none}
#cssmenu #head-mobile{display:block;padding:23px;color:#ddd;font-size:12px;font-weight:700}
.button{width:55px;height:46px;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;cursor:pointer;z-index: 12399994;}
.button:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:20px;display:block;height:4px;width:20px;border-top:2px solid #dddddd;border-bottom:2px solid #dddddd;content:''}
.button:before{-webkit-transition:all .3s ease;-ms-transition:all .3s ease;transition:all .3s ease;position:absolute;top:16px;right:20px;display:block;height:2px;width:20px;background:#ddd;content:''}
.button.menu-opened:after{-webkit-transition:all .3s ease;-ms-transition:all .3s ease;transition:all .3s ease;top:23px;border:0;height:2px;width:19px;background:#fff;-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);-o-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)}
.button.menu-opened:before{top:23px;background:#fff;width:19px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);-o-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)}
#cssmenu .submenu-button{position:absolute;z-index:99;right:0;top:0;display:block;border-left:1px solid #444;height:46px;width:46px;cursor:pointer}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened{background:#262626}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button{height:34px;width:34px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:19px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after{top:15px;right:13px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after{background:#fff}
#cssmenu .submenu-button:before{position:absolute;top:19px;right:22px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before{top:12px;right:16px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before{display:none}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a{border-left:none}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a{border-top:none}

.opener {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    position:relative;
    top:30%;
    color: rgba(14, 115, 230, 1.0);
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.opener-align {
    width:80%;
    background-color: rgba(245, 243, 243, 0.9);
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:5px 15px 5px 15px;
}

.opener-second {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    position:relative;
    top:45%;
    color: #DCB518;
    font-family: 'Yellowtail', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.opener-second-align {
    width:60%;
    background-color: rgba(42, 41, 33, 0.7);
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:5px 15px 5px 15px;
}


.parallax-transition-1 {
    text-align: center;
    top: 5%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

.parallax-transition-2 {
    text-align: center;
    top: 15%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

.services-annoucement-header {
    background-color: rgba(245, 243, 243, 0.9);
    border-radius: 15px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto 40px auto;
    font-family: 'Yellowtail', cursive;
    color: rgba(14, 115, 230, 1.0);
    font-size:40px;
    padding:15px 0px 15px 0px;
}

.hp-image-size {
width:45%;
height:auto;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.topic-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: rgba(245, 243, 243, 0.9);
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    height:30%;
    font-size:1em;
    margin-top:5%;
}

.topic-wrapper:hover {
    background-color: rgba(99,99,99,0.75);
    color: white;
}

.topic-wrapper2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(245, 243, 243, 0.9);
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    min-height: 310px;
}

.topic-wrapper2:hover {
    background-color: rgba(99,99,99,0.75);
    color: white;
}

.topic-text {
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
    text-align:justify;
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.parallax-icons {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    width:40%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon-text {
    margin-top: 0;
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
textarea {
    resize:none;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(245, 243, 243, 0.9);
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    height: 400px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

input {
    margin:auto;
}

.parallax {
        /* The image used */
        background-image: url("sunlife-building-mtl-digital-marketing.jpg");

        /* Full height */
        height: 100%;


        /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
}

.parallax2 {
        /* The image used */
        background-image: url("st-josephs-oratory-montreal-services.jpg");

        /* Full height */
        height: 100%;

        /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
}

} /* end of media query 700 width */
```

This is the small Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  (function($) {
$.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
 var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
   format: "dropdown",
   sticky: false
 }, options);
 return this.each(function() {
   $(this).find(".button").on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
     var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
     if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
       mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
     }
     else {
       mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
       if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
         mainmenu.find('ul').show();
       }
     }
   });
   cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
multiTg = function() {
     cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
     cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
       if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
         $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
       else {
         $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
     });
   };
   if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
   else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
   if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
resizeFix = function() {
  var mediasize = 700;
     if ($( window ).width() > mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').show();
     }
     if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
     }
   };
   resizeFix();
   return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
 });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
   format: "multitoggle"
});
});
})(jQuery);


});
```

I'm so lost as to why this is happening..

Comment: "I switch browsers after resizing my browser" - what do you mean by browser in this context? You switch from Chrome to something like Firefox, or you switch from one instance of Chrome to the other?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I will edit my post. What i meant by that is that i switch devices in inspect tool after resizing my browser from greater than 700px to something below it!

Comment: Thanks. Either way, this looks like a bug with Chrome, and therefore the only thing you can do is [file a bug report.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en) If it really bothers you, you could try Firefox's Responsive Design Mode (Ctrl+Shift+M).

Comment: Downloaded firefox. Same thing happening. I think it might be an issue with css class .topic-wrapper and me using a display: table-cell declaration... not sure. researching now!

Comment: I tried on Google Chrome but there are no error. RWD works well.